# Geofencing : GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to implement geofencing in my application so whenever the user enters one of the geofence objects, something will happen. Following the android developer guide (making your app location aware), when I add this snippet:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
```

I put this in my onMapReady() AFTER loading my geofences, so that they will immediately be added to my app. However, i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

I am sure I have built the google api client in my onCreate() but I still get this error. If I remove the above snippet (first code snippet) then the error is no longer there. What am i doing wrong?

Code:

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback {

```
//Google Maps
public GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
public Location mCurrentLocation;
private static final int FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int CONNECTION_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 2;
List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();

//Temporary Vars
double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;
Marker current_marker;

//Request Info vars
static final int GET_DETAILS = 1;
static final int EDIT_DETAILS = 2;


//Debug
private static final String TAG = "GeekysMessage";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
int markerCount;

private Toolbar toolbar;


//Geofence
private boolean mGeofencesAdded;
ArrayList mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
public int geofenceCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    buildGoogleAPIClient();
    //Geofence
    // Empty list for storing geofences.
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

    // Initially set the PendingIntent used in addGeofences() and removeGeofences() to null.
    mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    buildGoogleAPIClient();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

//LOCATION
private void buildGoogleAPIClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}



protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            updateUI();
        }
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    updateUI();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Updated",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void updateUI() {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection suspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 1);
        dialog.show();
    }
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}


int requestCode = 0;

//MAP
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //load all saved markers
    loadMarkers();

    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);

    //Permissions
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    } else {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }


}
private void loadMarkers() {

    // Opening the sharedPreferences object
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

    // Getting number of locations already stored
    markerCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("markerCount", 0);

    //if marker are already saved
    if (markerCount != 0) {

        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";
        String marker_title = null;
        String marker_snippet = null;
        int marker_radius = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < markerCount; i++) {
            lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat"+i, "0");
            lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng"+i, "0");
            marker_title = sharedPreferences.getString("title"+i, "");
            marker_snippet = sharedPreferences.getString("snippet"+i, "");
            marker_radius = sharedPreferences.getInt("radius"+i, 20);

            double lati = Double.valueOf(lat);
            double lngi = Double.valueOf(lng);

            addMarker(lati, lngi, marker_title, marker_snippet);
            addGeofence(marker_title, lati, lngi, marker_radius);

        }

    }
}
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public void addMarker(double lati, double longi, String title, String snippet){
    if (snippet==""){snippet = null;}
     Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
            .title(title)
             .snippet(snippet)
            .draggable(true));
    markerList.add(m);
}

public void saveMarkers(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    markerCount = 0;
    for (Marker i : markerList) {
        //Save to sharedprefences
        markerCount++;

        editor.putString("lat" + Integer.toString((markerCount - 1)), String.valueOf(i.getPosition().latitude));
        editor.putString("lng" + Integer.toString((markerCount - 1)), String.valueOf(i.getPosition().longitude));
        editor.putString("title" + Integer.toString((markerCount - 1)),i.getTitle());
        editor.putString("snippet" + Integer.toString((markerCount - 1)),i.getSnippet());
        editor.putInt("markerCount", markerCount);

        editor.commit();
    }
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

public void addGeofence(String key, double lat, double lng, int radius ){
    mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
            // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
            // geofence.
            .setRequestId(key)

            .setCircularRegion(
                    lat,
                    lng,
                    radius
            )
            .setExpirationDuration(12*60*60*1000)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                    Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build());

    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .radius(radius)
            .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#02bbff")));



}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        // Update state and save in shared preferences.
        mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                getString(mGeofencesAdded ? R.string.geofences_added :
                        R.string.geofences_removed),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    } else {
        // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                status.getStatusCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();` in `onStop()`. `LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(` code must be triggering onStop and so mGoogleApiClient is getting disconnected.

in onCreate

```
Boolean fromOnMapReady = false;
```

in OnMapReady

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
     fromOnMapReady = true;
```

in OnStop

```
protected void onStop() {
  if(!fromOnMapReady){
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
  super.onStop();
}
```

Once whatever process has finished running reset `fromOnMapReady = false` otherwise mGoogleApiClient will not be disconnected when required

Comment: did not work... i even deleted that event and still, cannot connect to google api ... any other suggestions?

Comment: is it getting connected even once?

Comment: dont worry i fixed it, ill give you the credit though :)